# Average value of character

Tags: c++

The below code tries to get the average value of the characters .
It works for the single character perfectly .But shows garbage value for characters

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
decltype(auto) avgval(T const*beg, T const *end)
{
    T total{};
    while (beg != end)
    {
        total += *beg;
        std::cout << "Total is " << total << "\n";
        ++beg;
    }
    return total;
}

int main()
{
    char name1[] = "A";
    int len = sizeof(name1) - 1;
    std::cout << avgval(name1, name1 + len) / len << "\n";
    char name[] = "ABC";
    int length = sizeof(name) - 1;
    std::cout << "name is " << avgval(name, name + length) / length << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Total is A
65
Total is A
Total is â
Total is ╞
name is -19
```

The expected result must be between 97 and 122 (ASCII values).However I see junk values returned .Any explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable `total` is of type `char` for this instance. `char` seems to be signed 8-bit number on your platform, and its range is -128 ~ 127.

The ASCII total of "ABC" is `65 + 66 + 67 = 198`, which exceeds the range.

Strictly speaking, the behavior is undefined. But if we consider it to be a 2's complement overflow, the binary representation would be `1100 0110`, which in turn interpreted to be -58. `rounddown(-58/3) = -19`.